# Facebook Android SDK walkthough

Tags: android

I'm trying to find a clear and detailed walk through on how to set up the Facebook sdk user logon inside my current app. Ive tried to do it on my own by using the Facebook example apps and their walk through but nothing i do works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of tutorials online, here are just a few:

1. [helloandroid.com part 1](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1) -- [helloandroid.com part 2](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-2)
2. [ericosgood.com](http://ericosgood.com/prog/facebook-android-sdk-tutorial/)
3. [android10.org](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/290-facebook-integration-in-your-android-application)